# How to formulate this transportation problem?

Tags: linear-programming, word-problem

I have been trying to formulate this as a transportation problem but I can't seem to do so:

We have $3$ types of projects and $3$ types of evaluators. We need to evaluate $61,40$ and $21$ projects of each type, respectively, and we have $5,3$ and $9$ evaluators of each type. Every evaluator can evaluate $15$ projects, and every project needs to be evaluated twice. **Furthermore, the second evaluation must be done by an evaluator of a different type than the first one.**

We are given the time each type of evaluator takes to evaluate every type of project, but that is not relevant for the formulation.

I tried to double the projects (so we have 6 destinations), but I don't know how to include that the second evaluator must be different.

Thanks

Comment: Is this the whole exercise? What is the goal?

Comment: Minimize the total time. My problem is formulating the problem, not solving it.

Comment: You have $122$ projects and $10$ evaluators total.  If each project needs two evaluators and each evaluator can do $15$ projects you can evaluate only $75$ projects.

Comment: That said, you could consider assigning the projects to three classes, where each class represents the two kinds of evaluator who will review it.

Comment: Sorry, there were 9 evaluators of type 3. Now we can evaluate (5+3+9)*15>122 projects

Comment: Another way to think of it would be to pretend that every project is evaluated by all three kinds of evaluators, then to remove one evaluation per project to get the best result.